# Explanation of $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{2+3}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2+3}{x}$$

I'm new in Calculus and limits, can you help me solve this?

I tried this way,

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2+3}{0}; \, x \gt 0 $$

$$\frac{5}{0} = \infty$$

But I was told the answer is wrong

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
If $f(x) =\frac{5}{x}$, check 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x) \text { and } \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x).$$ Do they seem to be equal?

---

Surely, it makes difference! In fact:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac 5x = -\infty \text { and } \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac 5x = +\infty,$$ thus $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac 5x$ does not exist. Here is the respective graph for the function $f(x) = \frac 5x$.  Notice the behavior of the function when $x$ is close to $0$.

[image]

---

As we can see from the graph as $x\to 0$ with direction to $1$ , we can see that the value of $f(x) \to -\infty$. This is what $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=-\infty$ (***left hand limit***) means. In the same way, as $x\to 0$ with direction to $-1$, we can see that the value of $f(x) \to +\infty$. This is exactly what $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f(x) =+\infty$ (***right hand limit***) means. Now, as I mentioned in the comments, the limit of $f$ as $x\to 0$ exists only if and only if $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\ell.$$ In that case we can say that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x) = \ell$. Note that $\ell$ can take any real value and $\infty, -\infty$, as well. In our case, we observe that the $2$ sided limits are not equal. Thus, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)$ does not exist.

---

Let's see the intuition why $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-} f(x) = -\infty$. Take a negative number, which is really close to $0$. Let's take for example the number $x_0=-10^{-6}$. We have that $f(x_0)=f(-10^{-6}) = - 5\cdot 10^6$. Now, take a negative number which is even closer to $0$ than $x_0$. Let's take $x_1 = -10^{-12}$. We have that $f(x_1) = -5\cdot 10^{12}$ which is a pretty small number and a lot smaller than $f(x_0)$. Thus, we understand that as $x\to 0^-$ the value of $f(x)$ goes to $-\infty$.

Comment: Does it matter to put a zero as a positive or negative, it makes no difference.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists iff $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x).$

Comment: You asked whether they look equal or not as judging by the fact its limit is 0 so it doesn't make any difference whether it's positive or negative, I guess they are equal or they are not.. Because in both cases it ends up as 5/0 anyway.

Comment: Can you tell me about the graph more because I don't understand why it doesn't exist or how.. And how can I in future differentiate whether a function at given point or limit exists or not.

Comment: @Baoute Answer edited. As far as differentiation is concerned, if the function is **not** continuous at a specific point, say $x_0$, then it is not differentiable at $x_0$ for sure! Otherwise, you need to check the existence of the limit $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}.$$

Comment: @Baoute I hope my answer covers you.

Comment: @thanasissdr He didn't mean differentiation in that sense, he meant how could he predict when a function's limit would exist or not..